# How to schedule a job in Jenkins pipeline everyday except 3rd Thursday

Tags: jenkins, cron, jenkins-pipeline

I am trying to schedule a cron job every day at 9AM except 3rd Thursday of each month. Any suggestion ?

Comment: Probably not doable solely in cron. Combine a daily schedule with a conditional build step to exit if Thursday and date range?

Answer (score -1):

Sorry below is for Jenkins freestyle job Not for Jenkins Pipeline

go to Build Triggers --> Build periodically then add this

once in every two hours slot between 9 AM and 5 PM every weekday (perhaps at 10:38 AM, 12:38 PM, 2:38 PM, 4:38 PM)
H H(9-16)/2 * * 1-5
or
every fifteen minutes (perhaps at :07, :22, :37, :52)
H/15 * * * *

Please adjust it yourself

Comment: Does not exclude 3rd Thursday.

Comment: Yes, I don't think it will exclude 3rd Thursday of each month